# Parallel execution library for Python

Tags: python

I search a parallel execution library for Python.

There are two in the standard library:

- [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)
- [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing)

I discovered, that simple tasks like handling timeouts are not easy with the standard library tools. [Handle multiprocessing.TimeoutError in multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37527085/handle-multiprocessing-timeouterror-in-multiprocessing-pool-map-async)

Some years ago I used celery, but this is too big for my current use case.

## Wanted features

- Serverless on local machine
- Should run on linux. Windows/Mac support not needed.
- Sane handling of ctrl-c
- Later, extending to compute on other machines should require only few source code changes.
- Optional: GUI for browsing job results.

Comment: Situation is not clear, nor updated. Too many libraries, not all propriate for clusters.

Comment: @jaromrax do you have a hint?

Comment: The question here is not clear. Specifically, why is the solution using multiprocessing's `apply_async` as suggested in the comment on the linked SO question is not an option ?

Also, what does _Sane handling of ctrl-c_ mean ? Would it be _sane_ to kill the current process but wait for all other forked processes to complete or would it be _sane_ to also send ctrl-c to the processes ? The decision should be left to the library user rather than the module implementation, imo.