# Best parallel python for a cluster

Tags: library, python

There is too unclear situation for beginner - what is propriate for my case please?

I have few PCs (Linux) with 4-8 cores each. All ssh accessible on 1 GB network. My function will contain a call to some previously compiled code, like `./work < input_file > output_file`. One evaluation can take a minute or even much more, I can run it several times in parallel.

I can see jug, scoop, pp, pathos? In the lists there are tens of packages and some may be too old. Only thing I know is I want to use new python - 3.5. Thank you.
No answer on similar q:
[Parallel execution library for Python](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33860/parallel-execution-library-for-python)

Comment: Rather than simply "parallel execution", it seems more like [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing). Have you tried [dispy](http://dispy.sourceforge.net/) or similar library?

Answer (score 1):

I went through several packages and **`pathos`** seems to work with my python 3.5.

```
from pathos.parallel import ParallelPool as Pool
import time
pool = Pool()

def host(id):
    import socket
    from math import sin
    sum=0
    for i in range(1,1000):
        for j in range(1,10000):
            sum=sum+sin(i/j)
    return "Rank: %d -- %s. %f" % (id, socket.gethostname(),sum+id)


pool.ncpus = 4
print("Evaluate on "+str(pool.ncpus)+" cpus")
pool.servers = ('localhost:5653','localhost:5654', 'Fil:5653')

res5 = pool.amap( host, range(16) )
while not res5.ready():
         time.sleep(1)
         print(stats()  )
print(  "\n".join(res5.get()) )
```

Provided I run  `ppserver.py -p 5653 -w 8 -t 300` 2x locally and on Fil node

If there is a better answer, give it please.